Compute $\mathbb{E}[X\mid X^2+Y^2]$,where $X$ and $Y$ are two independent Gaussian $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ r.v.

Question:Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent Gaussian
$\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ random variables.How to compute $\mathbb{E}[X\mid
 X^2+Y^2]$?

Here is my attempt:
I use the fact that if $Z$ is $\sigma(X^2+Y^2)$ measurable,then there exists a function $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ such that $Z=g(X^2+Y^2)$
Using this fact,let $Z$ be a $\sigma(X^2+Y^2)$ measurable random variable I try to compute:$$\begin{align}&
\mathbb E[X\cdot Z]=\mathbb E[X\cdot g(X^2+Y^2)]\\&=\mathbb E[\Phi(X,Y)]=\frac1{2\pi}\iint_{\mathbb R^2}xg(x^2+y^2)\exp(\frac{-(x^2+y^2)}{2})dxdy
\end{align}$$Where $\Phi(X,Y)=X\cdot g(X^2+Y^2)$.
To find $\mathbb E[X\mid X^2+Y^2]$,which is again $\sigma(X^2+Y^2)$ measurable,we can write $\mathbb E[X\mid X^2+Y^2]$ as $f(X^2+Y^2)$,now compute$$\begin{align}&
\mathbb E[f(X^2+Y^2)g(X^2+Y^2)]\\&=\frac1{2\pi}\iint_{\mathbb R^2}f(x^2+y^2)g(x^2+y^2)\exp(\frac{-(x^2+y^2)}{2})dxdy
\end{align}$$Now,only need to find a function such that $$f(x^2+y^2)=x$$But how can I get such function?I am stuck here.
Any help would be appreciated.

You do not need to find this, but the conditional density $f(x \mid X^2+Y^2=k)= \dfrac{1}{\pi(k-x^2)}\mathbf{I}_{[-\sqrt{k}\lt x \lt \sqrt{k}]}$ is symmetric about $x=0$ and has bounded support.  It has conditional expectation of $0$ and conditional variance of $\frac k2$.

Let $Z=-X$. Then $Z^2=X^2$ and $(Z,Y)$ has the same distribution as $(X,Y)$ so $$\mathbb E[X|X^2+Y^2]=-\mathbb E[Z|X^2+Y^2]=-\mathbb E[Z|Z^2+Y^2]=-\mathbb E[X|X^2+Y^2]$$
so
$$\mathbb E[X|X^2+Y^2]=0.$$

+1. It helps that $ |X| =\sqrt{X^2} \le  \sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ and so $\mathbb E[X\mid X^2+Y^2]$ must be something finite.
